# How to Prove $(A \times B) \cup C=(A \times C) \cup (B \times C)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, elementary-set-theory

if $A$, $B$ and $C$ are any three sets in an Universal Set $U$

Prove $(A \times B) \cup C=(A \times C) \cup (B \times C)$

I have seen this here http://www.math.uvic.ca/faculty/gmacgill/guide/RF.pdf

I still have a doubt that $A \times B$ is an Ordered pair , But $C$ is single object. How can we take union?

Comment: $\cup$ does not mean intersection

Comment: You can take the union of any two sets. $\{x\}\cup \{\Delta, (a,b,c)\} = \{x, \Delta, (a,b,c)\}$

Comment: Yes LHS is of the form $\left\{(a,b),c)\right\}$  but RHS is of the from $\left\{(a,b)\right\}$ right?

Comment: I agree it is false. It is easy to see also when $C$ is empty.

Comment: I guess its a typo right,LHS should be $(A \cup B) \times C$

Comment: That is also false when $C$ is empty

Comment: why it is false

Comment: The LHS should be $(A\cup B)\times C$, I believe

Comment: the cartesian product with an empty set is empty

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger The link he provided listed this identity (which I believe is false) in addition to that one. So this is correctly typed, at least as the link puts it.

Answer (score 2):

CPR3 in your linked notes has 2 true statements:

- (a) $A \times (B \cup C) = (A \times B) \cup (A \times C)$.
- (b) $ A \times (B \cap C) = (A \times B) \cap (A \times C)$.

Their proof are simple double inclusion arguments.
And two false ones:

- (c) $A \cup (B \times C) = (A \cup B) \times (A \cup C)$.
- (d) $A \cap (B \times C) = (A \cap B) \times (A \cap C)$.

which don't even make sense if you look at the types: in the right hand side we have only pairs (and $A$ is just a set in the coordinates), while on the left hand side $A$ should thus also be a set of pairs, which it need not be.

So you can find all sorts of trivial counterexamples: $A = \{0\}, B = \{1\}, C =\{2\}$, then the left hand side of (c) becomes $\{0, (1,2)\}$, and the right hand side becomes $\{(0,0), (0,2), (1,0), (1, 2)\}$, which is completely different. For (d) to fail we can use similarly trivial examples $A = \{1\} = B = C$ gives the RHS equal to $\{1\} \times \{1\} = \{(1,1)\}$ and the LHS equal to $\{1\} \cap \{(1,1)\} = \emptyset$, as $1 \neq (1,1)$.

Maybe the author meant to write:

- (c') $(A \cup B) \times C  = (A \times C) \cup (B \times C)$.
- (d') $(A \cap B) \times C  = (A \times C) \cap (B \times C)$.

which *are* true, and all have similar proofs. E.g. the last one: $(x,y) \in (A \cap B) \times C$ iff $x \in A \cap B$ and $y \in C$ iff ($x \in A$ and $y \in C$) (so $(x,y) \in A \times C$) *and* $(x \in B)$ (and still $(y \in C)$), so $(x,y) \in (B \times C)$, so $(x,y)$ is in the RHS.